# Can we create something similar to {{ content_for_index }} as per our requirement and use it in the pages we want? SHOPIFY Theme

Tags: shopify

In the shopify theme that I am editing I want to create a page where there are so many sections. I am searching for a way to allow admin user to change the order of all the sections from the customiser.

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around for changing the order of all the sections.

[credit]
this solution is based on one post from shopify community: https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Nested-Sections/td-p/424873

I have created five files where you can see my workaround

[Files]

1. templates/page.sequence.liquid
2. sections/a.liquid
3. sections/b.liquid
4. sections/c.liquid
5. sections/seq.liquid

templates/page.sequence.liquid

```html
{%capture one%}{% section 'a' %}{%endcapture%}
{%capture two%}{% section 'b' %}{%endcapture%}
{%capture three%}{% section 'c' %}{%endcapture%}

{% capture collection_template_content %}
    {% section 'seq' %}
{% endcapture %}

{% assign one = one | replace: 'class="shopify-section"', 'class="shopify-section-nested"' %}
{% assign two = two | replace: 'class="shopify-section"', 'class="shopify-section-nested"' %}
{% assign three = three | replace: 'class="shopify-section"', 'class="shopify-section-nested"' %}

{% assign collection_template_content = collection_template_content | replace: "%%a%%", one %}
{% assign collection_template_content = collection_template_content | replace: "%%b%%", two %}
{% assign collection_template_content = collection_template_content | replace: "%%c%%", three %}

{{collection_template_content}}
```

sections/a.liquid (and two more similar files: b.liquid and c.liquid)

```html
<div >
    Section A
</div>

{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Section A",
    "settings": [

    ]
  }
{% endschema %}

{% stylesheet %}
{% endstylesheet %}

{% javascript %}
{% endjavascript %}
```

sections/seq.liquid

```html
<div class="page-width">
  
{% if section.settings.id_a == "1"%}%%a%%{% endif %}
{% if section.settings.id_b == "1"%}%%b%%{% endif %}
{% if section.settings.id_c == "1"%}%%c%%{% endif %}

{% if section.settings.id_a == "2"%}%%a%%{% endif %}
{% if section.settings.id_b == "2"%}%%b%%{% endif %}
{% if section.settings.id_c == "2"%}%%c%%{% endif %}

{% if section.settings.id_a == "3"%}%%a%%{% endif %}
{% if section.settings.id_b == "3"%}%%b%%{% endif %}
{% if section.settings.id_c == "3"%}%%c%%{% endif %}

</div>
{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Section Main",
    "settings": [
    {
         "type": "select",
         "id": "id_a",
         "label": "Order A",
         "options": [
           {
             "group": "value",
             "value": "1",
             "label": "1"
           },
           {
             "group": "value",
             "value": "2",
             "label": "2"
           },
           {
             "group": "value",
             "value": "3",
             "label": "3"
           }
         ],
         "default": "1",
         "info": "text"
      },
{
         "type": "select",
         "id": "id_b",
         "label": "Order B",
         "options": [
           {
             "group": "value",
             "value": "1",
             "label": "1"
           },
           {
             "group": "value",
             "value": "2",
             "label": "2"
           },
           {
             "group": "value",
             "value": "3",
             "label": "3"
           }
         ],
         "default": "1",
         "info": "text"
      },
{
         "type": "select",
         "id": "id_c",
         "label": "Order C",
         "options": [
           {
             "group": "value",
             "value": "1",
             "label": "1"
           },
           {
             "group": "value",
             "value": "2",
             "label": "2"
           },
           {
             "group": "value",
             "value": "3",
             "label": "3"
           }
         ],
         "default": "1",
         "info": "text"
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}

{% stylesheet %}
{% endstylesheet %}

{% javascript %}
{% endjavascript %}
```

One problem with this is, the theme customiser is not happy if we use such workaround, I have an error as shown in the snapshot, other then that, the content works just fine when we visit the page.[open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07HKh.png)